# French accents on Yosemite

Tags: macos

How can I set my macbook pro to type the French accents by showing them on top of each vowel instead of pressing option keys?

On a English keyboard.

Comment: I assume you have a French keyboard ?

Comment: no, i want to use the english standard one

Comment: I use to have that before the update to Yosemite

Comment: Try adding a French or Spanish keyboard to the list in system prefs/keyboard/input sources and restarting.

Answer (score 1):

From Apple KB - [OS X Yosemite: Enter characters with accent marks](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18436?locale=en_GB&viewlocale=en_US)

> 1. Press and hold a key on the keyboard (for example, e) to display an accent menu.
>
>    If the key you press and hold doesn’t have any possible accent marks, the menu isn’t shown.
> 2. Select a character (for example, é).
>
>    Click a character, press the number key shown for a character, or use the arrow keys to cycle through the characters. Then press the Space bar to select one.
>
> You can also enter characters with accent marks using the Keyboard Viewer or Character Viewer.
>
> [Use the Keyboard Viewer](https://support.apple.com/kb/index?page=link&apdid=mchlp1015&viewlocale=en_US&bookId=Mac%20Help135122)
>   [Use the Character Viewer](https://support.apple.com/kb/index?page=link&apdid=mchlp1560&viewlocale=en_US&bookId=Mac%20Help135122)
>   [Use input sources to type in other languages](https://support.apple.com/kb/index?page=link&apdid=mchlp1406&viewlocale=en_US&bookId=Mac%20Help135122)
>   [Format text in documents](https://support.apple.com/kb/index?page=link&apdid=mchlp2544&viewlocale=en_US&bookId=Mac%20Help135122)

The press & hold accent menu can be enabled or disabled from Terminal

To disable the character accent menu in OS X, launch Terminal from /Applications/Utilities, enter the following command and press Return:

`defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false`

To re-enable, change `false` to `true`